# Display Products in Home Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

Here are my questions
1.) How to display products of specific category?
2.) How can I organize the way it is displayed? (column, size, row, etc) ?

Hi. I have tried almost all the tutorials in google but I failed to display products in my Home Page. Although displaying "all products" is not working, the displaying of new items works fine. This is what I did so far.

This is the line of code which works:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Though the code above works, the way it displays the product is not right.

This line of code doesn't work:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Yes, I have tried clearing the cache as well. Also, I am using Magento 1.9.2.3.

UPDATE:
After following the instruction, something was displayed:
[image]

Although something was displayed on my homepage, this is not how I expect the products to be displayed. Why does it display like this ?

Comment: All your products are inside the category ID equal 3?

Comment: can please try this echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product_list")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list.phtml")->setCategoryId('category_id')->toHtml();

Comment: I'm sorry. But where do I paste that? I am new to Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have using **`magento c.E 1.9 version`** and this version 
 already **applied magento patch** [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788).

So,you need to remove **`catalog/product_list`** from  white list

1. *`System > Permissions > Blocks`*
2. *Add New Block*
3. *Block Name: `catalog/product_list`*
4. *Is Allowed : Yes*

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Something was displayed on my home page. But there is still a problem. Please see my update. Thank you.

Comment: may be there are some code which is creating the issue after sort by

Comment: just remove the toolbar code from list.phtml and check

Comment: Woah, okay I found the file and removed the toolbar. But will removing that toolbar not affect other modules? Will it really be okay to remove that?

Comment: Change the template you use to your own template. Don't use catalog/product/list.phtml and restore the toolbar code back in the list.phtml template. Your display will then be specific to your template, and not affect anything else.

Comment: No.There must be some issue at toolbar code... You need to resolved this issue bcoz list.phtml also use for category & search page. Or Else use  make  repilcate of  `list.phtml` file and use this phtml for u r home page  with remove toolbar

Comment: @ProxiBlue,i am agree with u.